# Reclassify values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, reclassify

I'd like to question about reclassify on this type of thing for ArcGIS 10.1. I tried this method but I know it gave me problems. I know this was from 2005 and ArcGIS has changed since then.

My question here is HOW can someone set up ranges like this be able into ArcGIS 10.1. I tried to follow this but I knew there was something was not right. I'd like to hear from other who might have experience this type of thing. When you put a new values the only way you can do is single values, single ranges with one hyphen and text.

Here is the example :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually enter multiple ranges of values as a single entry in the Reclassify tool if you use a semicolon between ranges.  An example reclassify input from your screenshot would be: **Old Values** 333 - 334; 433 - 434 **New Values** 21.  When you click away from your entry (either to run the tool or add another entry), you will see that the tool automatically makes multiple entries containing your ranges of values.  An example entry:
[image]

And then when you select OK or modify your number of entries, the tool automatically creates additonal entries pertaining to each of your ranges:
[image]

I hope I understood your question and this helps.

Comment: THank you !!! Yes I understand especially what you showed me..that help !

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't know you could do this :)

Comment: @PROBERT if this answers your question you should give it the little green check mark under the number (at the top left)!

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea and not tested, but: Try adding a new field, calculating that field to some "group" value based on your requirements above (because field calculator can handle these more complex cases), then reclassifying based on that new single-value "group"